# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement qgis

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, r, rqgis

I want to use the RQGIS

```
library(RQGIS)
# set the environment, i.e. specify all the paths necessary to run QGIS from 
# within R
set_env()

Trying to find QGIS LTR in C:/OSGEO4~1
$`root`
[1] "C:/OSGeo4W64"

$qgis_prefix_path
[1] "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis"

$python_plugins
[1] "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/python/plugins"

# under Windows set_env would be much faster if you specify the root path:
# set_env("C:/OSGeo4W~1")

find_algorithms(search_term = "([Pp]olygon)(centroid)")
Error in py_run_string_impl(code, local, convert) : 
  NameError: name 'processing' is not defined
  attach RQGIS
```

I search this problem, and I knew it's python-QGIS problem.

So I tried below, but it shows this error

```
pip install qgis

**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement qgis (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for qgis**
```

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

RQGIS only works with QGIS2, and I assume that you have already installed QGIS3. Hence, use **RQGIS3**, you can find it under https://github.com/jannes-m/RQGIS3. So far, it is not on CRAN due to an RStudio issue under Linux/Mac.